# Google Api Calendar "$service->calendars->insert($calendar)"

Tags: api, calendar, google-api, google-calendar-api

I am new in it but I want to use google API with PHP but it doesn't work. I have created the `service` param `$service = new Google_Service_Books($client);` and after I tried `$service->calendars->insert($calendar);` and I have `Notice: Undefined property: Google_Service_Books::$calendars`. `Calendars` is the problem but now I don't know what I have to do.
src:
https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/start/get_started
https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/calendars/insert#auth

Any ideas?

Comment: Your question is about Calendars, but it looks like you are creating a service for Books instead. You need to create a calendar service `$service = new Google_Service_Calendar($client);` If you haven't already read [this](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/php) it might be helpful.

Comment: I follow the tutorial to create a calendar, but in one page they use param "$service", and I looked to find where and how they used it. Except this "$service = new Google_Service_Books($client);", I didn't find how create "$service" param.

Comment: I have an new error but it seems to works with "$service = new Google_Service_Calendar($client);", thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Don't Panic, it was really that "$service = new Google_Service_Calendar($client);"